# CORS enabled but access still denied

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, xmlhttprequest, cors

For reference I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and Windows 10.

I have an MVC webapi project designed using a template provided by Visual Studio with accounts that are stored in an SQL database. I have another project which is the website itself that the users log into. I'm attempting to debug in VS but am being met with an access is denied error message whenever a GET request is made outside of the initial login. I've enabled CORS on the webapi but it didn't seem to make much of a difference.

Here's how I enabled CORS.

In the WebAPIConfig file I have the following:

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.EnableCors();

        // Web API configuration and services
        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

And then in the Web.config file I have this:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

This is the code from the website making the call:

```
function getProfilePicture(username){
    var returnValue = [];

    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET", 'http://localhost:60690/api/ProfilePicture?Username=' + username, false);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('accessToken'));
        xmlhttp.send();
        if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            returnValue = jQuery.parseJSON(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

The error message says "SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied."

Did I not properly enable CORS?

**Update**

I downloaded Postman in an attempt to figure out the issue. I'm actually able to make GET calls with Postman without any errors. It's returning the data and everything. One thing I did notice is it doesn't look like the Authorization header is actually being sent. It's missing from the data in Fiddler.

Comment: You might want to test without the normal appConfig constructs:  

 string corsDomain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CorsAllowedDomain"];
            EnableCorsAttribute cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(corsDomain, "*", "*")
            {
                SupportsCredentials = true
            };
            config.EnableCors(cors);

Try with "CorsAllowedDomain" set to "*".

Comment: @programmerj doing that gets me this error message "Multiple Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers are not allowed for CORS response." :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` as a response header is **incompatible** with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`. If you're going to use credentials, you **must** use `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <value-of-origin-request-header>`.

Comment: I did that but I'm still getting the error message. :(

Comment: @Rhendar, If you marked this as the correct answer, does that mean you managed to get it working?

Comment: Eventually, yeah. I think I was essentially instantiating CORS twice. Your post put me on the right path. Thanks.